# BASH script for extracting archives - how to make the script ask for folder destination?

Tags: bash, scripts, tar

I've started using the bash script below, for unpacking archives. How would I go about making the script ask if I would like to specify a folder, or just use the default folder to extract to?

I'd like to be able to run the archive script, and get a prompt saying:

"Extract to default folder Y, or N, instead specify folder (enter folder).
Any help appreciated :)

Excerpt from .bashrc

```
extract () {
if [ -f $1 ] ; then
  case $1 in
    *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf $1     ;;
    *.tar.gz)    tar xzf $1     ;;
    *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1     ;;
    *.rar)       unrar e $1     ;;
    *.gz)        gunzip $1      ;;
    *.tar)       tar xf $1      ;;
    *.tbz2)      tar xjf $1     ;;
    *.tgz)       tar xzf $1     ;;
    *.zip)       unzip $1       ;;
    *.Z)         uncompress $1  ;;
    *.7z)        7z x $1        ;;
    *)     echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via extract()" ;;
     esac
 else
     echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
 fi
}
```

Comment: In general what you're asking is difficult, since not all the tools incorporate this feature. For them, you'll have to extract someplace and then copy over.

Comment: @muru Why? Who forbids you to change working directory?

Answer (score 1):

As for your code:

- Do not put error messages to `STDOUT`, there is `STDERR` for them.
- Do not forget to enclose filenames (and veriables in general) in quotes. `tar xjf $1` would not work if `$1` contains spaces.
- `gunzip` and `bunzip2` without `-k` (`--keep`) option delete compressed file after decomressing. Are you sure you want it?
- GNU `tar` can detect compression format by its own, just do not force it: `$ tar xf "$1"`. But let it be as you wish.

As for the task, I would not implement it as a function in `.bashrc` but as a script. So it may look like that, I think:

```
#!/bin/bash

# config
DEFAULT_TARGET="."

SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}"

err() {
    printf >&2 "$SCRIPTNAME: $*\n"
    exit 1
}

ARC="$1"
[[ -f $ARC ]] || err $"'$ARC' does not exist"
ARC="$(readlink -f "$ARC")"

read -p "Extract to [default: $DEFAULT_TARGET]: " TARGET
[[ -z $TARGET ]] &&\
    TARGET="$DEFAULT_TARGET"
[[ -d $TARGET ]] || err $"Directory '$TARGET' does not exist"
[[ -w $TARGET ]] || err $"Permission denied: '$TARGET' is not writable"

cd "$TARGET"
case "$ARC" in
    *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.tar.gz)    tar xzf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.bz2)       bunzip2 "$ARC"     ;;
    *.rar)       unrar e "$ARC"     ;;
    *.gz)        gunzip "$ARC"      ;;
    *.tar)       tar xf "$ARC"      ;;
    *.tbz2)      tar xjf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.tgz)       tar xzf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.zip)       unzip "$ARC"       ;;
    *.Z)         uncompress "$ARC"  ;;
    *.7z)        7z x "$ARC"        ;;
    *)           echo "'$ARC' cannot be extracted by $SCRIPTNAME" ;;
esac
```

Do you need any comments?

Comment: `-f $ARC` => `-f "$ARC"` same with `$TARGET` several places.

Comment: @Hannu Where? In `readlink -f "$ARC"` it was already quoted. Inside `[[]]` quotes are superfluous, unless `$` is on the right side of `==`.

Comment: Well it is inside [[]] - the line after `read -p ...` - I'd add them still just because of making it be "a good habit". Relying on esoteric "don't need it here" is prone to break things sooner or later.

Comment: @Hannu Nothing esoteric here, that’s a syntax of language. But, yes, it would break things sooner or later, if one would put quotes automatically around any `$var`. E. g. when one would put it inside `(())`.

Comment: ;-) `E. g. when one would put it inside (())` made me curious, wouldn't that depend on how you use quotes rather that automatically breaking it? I currently believe that I need the quotes everywhere; do I have reason to reconsider it? Please point me to an example. Or is that implying due to quoting numbers?

Comment: @Hannu `$ echo $(( $i ))` – valid, `$ echo $(( "$i" ))` – invalid.

Comment: With e.g. `i=100` yes.

Comment: @Hannu Common way to use vars inside `(())` it without `$`: `$ echo $(( i ))` of course, but anyway.

Comment: Right, `(( ))` and using numbers is a valid exception. `[[]]` works well with quotes though. (FWIW I'm an old Amiga REXX user, numbers are strings as everything else in REXX)